# Best object detection and tracking algorithm

Tags: opencv, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am newbie for Opencv. I want to create a object detection algorithm which tracks a football player. I want to know who is that player what's his jersey number. I want to know is the best way to find it. Which algorithm should i use. I have done one project which tracks user with color range in which i have converted each video image to `hsv`. But the challenge is coming to me is that after detecting player how can i find the jersey number.

Here is my Code -

```
#Import libraries
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np

# import the necessary packages
from collections import deque
import numpy as np
import cv2
import imutils
import time


#Reading the video
vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('football.mp4')
success,image = vidcap.read()

count = 0
success = True
idx = 0

#Read the video frame by frame
while success:
    #converting into hsv image
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    #green range
    lower_green = np.array([40,40, 40])
    upper_green = np.array([70, 255, 255])
    #blue range
    lower_blue = np.array([110,50,50])
    upper_blue = np.array([130,255,255])

    #Red range
    lower_red = np.array([0,31,255])
    upper_red = np.array([176,255,255])

    #white range
    lower_white = np.array([0,0,0])
    upper_white = np.array([0,0,255])

    #Define a mask ranging from lower to uppper
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_green, upper_green)
    #Do masking
    res = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=mask)

    #convert to hsv to gray
    res_bgr = cv2.cvtColor(res,cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
    res_gray = cv2.cvtColor(res,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    #Defining a kernel to do morphological operation in threshold image to 
    #get better output.
    kernel = np.ones((13,13),np.uint8)
    thresh = cv2.threshold(res_gray,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
    thresh = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)


    #find contours in threshold image     
    im2,contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    prev = 0
    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX

    for c in contours:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        #Detect players
        if(h>=(1.5)*w):
            if(w>15 and h>= 15):
                idx = idx+1
                player_img = image[y:y+h,x:x+w]
                player_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(player_img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
                #If player has blue jersy
                mask1 = cv2.inRange(player_hsv, lower_blue, upper_blue)
                res1 = cv2.bitwise_and(player_img, player_img, mask=mask1)
                res1 = cv2.cvtColor(res1,cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
                res1 = cv2.cvtColor(res1,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

                nzCount = cv2.countNonZero(res1)
                #If player has red jersy
                mask2 = cv2.inRange(player_hsv, lower_red, upper_red)
                res2 = cv2.bitwise_and(player_img, player_img, mask=mask2)
                res2 = cv2.cvtColor(res2,cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
                res2 = cv2.cvtColor(res2,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
                nzCountred = cv2.countNonZero(res2)

                if(nzCount >= 20):
                    #Mark blue jersy players as france
                    cv2.putText(image, 'France', (x-2, y-2), font, 0.8, (255,0,0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
                    cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),3)
                else:
                    pass
                if(nzCountred>=20):
                    #Mark red jersy players as belgium
                    cv2.putText(image, 'Belgium', (x-2, y-2), font, 0.8, (0,0,255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
                    cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,0,255),3)
                else:
                    pass
        if((h>=1 and w>=1) and (h<=30 and w<=30)):
            player_img = image[y:y+h,x:x+w]

            player_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(player_img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
            #white ball  detection
            mask1 = cv2.inRange(player_hsv, lower_white, upper_white)
            res1 = cv2.bitwise_and(player_img, player_img, mask=mask1)
            res1 = cv2.cvtColor(res1,cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
            res1 = cv2.cvtColor(res1,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            nzCount = cv2.countNonZero(res1)


            if(nzCount >= 3):
                # detect football
                cv2.putText(image, 'football', (x-2, y-2), font, 0.8, (0,255,0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
                cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),3)


    cv2.imwrite("./Cropped/frame%d.jpg" % count, res)
    # print('Read a new frame: ', success)    # save frame as JPEG file 
    count += 1
    cv2.imshow('Match Detection',image)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
    success,image = vidcap.read()

vidcap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with a dummy project using a neural network with a pre-trained coco model:
https://github.com/Icy3D/hello-coco-py

[image: Detected objects: person and car]

If you need more learn how to reduce the number of classes to be detected (person, car, bus, ..). If you need more sophicsticated solutions train your own neural network or fit an existing network to your needs (google for transfer learning).

Anyhow you should [get familiar with tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/).

Comment: Hi, thank you for your valuable answer. I need some more guidance as i am very new to opencv and would appreciate your assistance.

Comment: Hey - I'm glad to help regarding specifics, BUT I can't teach you opencv. Once you have the players bounding box you need to track it from frame to frame. And for the jersey number I'd recommend to use OCR to extract the number. Have a look at this tutorial:
https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/09/17/opencv-ocr-and-text-recognition-with-tesseract/

Comment: Great... thanks... I am learning a course on opencv. And  i hope you don't mind if I have future queries. Appreciate your help. Thank you Stackoverflow friend.

Answer (score 1):

The question of the "best algorithm to perform X on (new dataset or task) Y" is quite invalid for learning algorithms since they are all tuned for our applications, based on the data that we trained them on and no optimality is (or can be) guaranteed.

Detection algorithms nowadays use large variety of mechanisms, from object detection using deep learning, Kalman filtering to track and incorporation of different contexts and fusion.

You could ask your self on the difference between tracking and detection. Try and find the differences between detecting (perfectly) an object (of the same instance) in several frames vs tracking it through using the time information. If you could find all the objects perfectly, and number the instances consistently, what is the difference now?

I can refer you to numerous sources for studying it, for examples [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/object-detection-and-tracking-in-pytorch-b3cf1a696a98) Medium article, [detectron](https://github.com/facebookresearch/Detectron) of facebook (based on Mask-RCNN) and so on. Try various combination of keywords in google to enhance your results: "object detection deep learning" (filter it for 2017 and above), "object tracking" in scholar...

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can use OpenCV for object tracking:

[Object Tracking OpenCV](https://github.com/RubensZimbres/Repo-2017/blob/master/Object%20Tracking%20OpenCV)

Then train your own OpenCV cascade to recognize the jersey number:

[OpenCV Customized Cascade Training + Facial Landmarks](https://github.com/RubensZimbres/Repo-2018/tree/master/OpenCV)

For more info on OpenCV installation, refer to:

https://www.pyimagesearch.com/ and

https://www.learnopencv.com/

This is what you probaby need:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qA1dYQSANO8

Answer (score 1):

You can check from this recent paper (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1902.03524.pdf) that the CNN developed by Baidu is state of the art in image recognition problem.